# Установление зависимостей в Maven

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Всем привет, я новичок в автоматизации сборки проектов, а вопрос следующий. Я написал программу с использованием библиотеки mysql-connector-java и платформы JavaFX, всё работает. Начинаю её конвертировать в maven-проект, устанавливаю зависимость:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenNetwork</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenNetwork</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.25</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
   
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
   </dependency>
   
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-media -->
   
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build> 
</project>
```

На выходе получаю готовый jar-ник. Запускаю jar-файл, меню показывает, но потом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя без Maven всё работало. Структура проекта такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть варик что javaFX 8й версии, а коннектор для 9+

И идея сама парсит конфликт этих зависимостей

Посмотрите, не конфликтуют ли у вас зависимость коннектора с версией жабы